Ergodicity-definition for general statistic
I'm struggling with the definition of ergodicity within time series. Consider a time series denoted as $X = (X_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}$, where each $X_i$ represents a random vector defined on the same probability space. Assume strict stationarity of $X$ and denote by $x_1, \dots, x_n$ the observed values (data).
Within this context, I'm dealing with a statistic that takes $x_1, \dots, x_n$ as inputs and yields a real number. Let's refer to this statistic as $\psi$, where $\psi(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in\mathbb{R}$. The purpose of $\psi$ is to estimate a theoretical value of the underlying process, denoted as $\Psi\in\mathbb{R}$.
I would like to show that $\psi(X_1, \dots, X_n) \overset{P}{\to} \Psi$ as $n\to\infty$.
1) Suppose $\Psi$ can be expressed as a function of the distribution of $X_1$ (for example, $\Psi = \mathbb{E}(X_i)$ or $\Psi = \text{quantile}(X_i)$). I've established the following: if we're given an iid random sample $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ where the distribution of $Y_i \overset{D}{=} X_1$ matches the marginal distribution of $X$, then $\psi(Y_1, \dots, Y_n) \overset{P}{\to} \Psi$ as $n\to\infty$.
Question: What assumptions do we need about the time series to ensure that $\psi(X_1, \dots, X_n) \overset{P}{\to} \Psi$ as $n\to\infty$? The key concept here is ergodicity, yet there is no universally accepted definition. If $\Psi = \mathbb{E}(X_i)$, then we require what is known as mean-ergodicity, which essentially asserts that the mean converges to the expectation. However, how do we frame this for our scenario where $\Psi$ takes a different form? Alternatively, are there any results indicating that assuming something like $\beta$-mixing alongside stationarity can lead to this convergence?
2) The same question applies, but now $\Psi$ can be expressed as a function of the joint distribution of $(X_1, X_2)$. For instance, consider $\Psi = \text{cov}(X_i, X_{i+1})$. Here, $\psi$ takes the form $\psi(X_1, \dots, X_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f(X_i, X_{i+1})$ for some known function $f$.
I've demonstrated that if we have an iid random sample from $(X_1, X_2)$, denoted as $(Y_1, Y_2)_1, \dots, (Y_1, Y_2)_n$, then $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f((Y_1, Y_2)_i)$ tends in probability to $\Psi$ as $n$ approaches infinity. What assumptions are necessary for $\psi(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ to tend in probability to $\Psi$ as $n$ approaches infinity?

Take a look at Stochastic processes by Doob (1953), page 465; it could be helpful.

... also not that stationarity in its weak sense is not sufficient for "ergodicity in mean".
